# SUM function returns a number with many fractional digits

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Consider the query below.  The `Quantity` column is of type REAL

```
SELECT Quantity
FROM foo
WHERE ID = 202224
```

[image]

However, doing a SUM results in many fractional digits (e.g. digits after decimal place):

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity)
FROM foo
WHERE ID = 202224
```

[image]

I can fix it by casting the result back to REAL:

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(Quantity) AS REAL)
FROM foo
WHERE ID = 202224
```

[image]

This feels like the wrong way to solve this problem.  And it adds an extra `Compute Scalar` to the query plan.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: `REAL` is a floating-point data type. Performing arithmetic with floats will 99.9% of the time produce this result. I think the only *real* (pun completely intended) way to do this would probably be to cast to a `DECIMAL` before summing them because decimals don't do any approximation.

Comment: In other words `SELECT SUM(CAST(Quantity AS decimal(38,19))...` See also [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), no it isn't, you just have to understand the results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)